# Some problems regarding my website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I bought a website yesterday, my website was working perfectly on WAMP but now i have some issues:

1:
my website is csgodonut.com , it is working like it should but when i put www. infront of the url then the whole website stops working. When you try logging in using steam then u go back to the login page, but then when you go to csgodonut.com without www. it works like it should.

2:
i still need to use csgodonut.com/index.php/home/home to go to other pages than home even though i have:

#### .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

#### config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = ""; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: This is not a coding question. You can make www.csgodonut.com go to csgodonut.com source directory by using the tools your hosting provider has in place to handle subdomains.

Comment: okay, thanks for the reply

Comment: This question is getting downvoted because it's off-topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your question to the correct queue

How ever

try with this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site_folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: without the <files> ? Thanks for reply

Comment: Try too removing the .htacces from application folder